# Calling the same function multiple times causes faster execution?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to do some simple and naive performance tests parsing a large JSON file with Dart and Flutter using Stopwatch to measure the time that passed between start of the parsing and when parsing finishes. The code is behind a button and looks similar to this:

```
final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
modelFromJson(jsonStr);
stopwatch.stop();
final executionTime = stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds;
stopwatch.reset();
print('JSON parser executed in ${executionTime}');
```

On the very first iteration of this code, the runtime seems to be around 400ms+, any consecutive iteration takes between 5-90ms - so 4-20times LESS time than the first execution.

This makes me wonder, is the dart runtime utilizing any optimizations or caching strategies here or am I missing something else in this case?

Comment: Even if the Dart runtime isn't doing any explicit caching itself, the operating system and hardware often will do some amount of caching.  For example, data in memory might need to be paged in, and there usually are multiple levels of caches when reading from a disk and multiple levels of caches between RAM and the CPU.

Comment: Right, if that's the case though, I would expect that to be the same or similar with other languages though - which doesn't seem to be the case. Having done the same test on Kotlin and Swift doesn't show such huge decreases in computational time though if any. So either Dart is utilizing that in way bigger proportions or there's likely something else going on! Thanks for your answer